# Internal Redirections?

Tags: redirect, core

I'm facing too many redirections issue with the REST API, and only with it, GUI works like a charm. I used cloudflare as a CDN. When I disable Cloudflare, REST API is working, else not.
I was testing redirections with CURL to detect issues and saw that there was a redirection when accessing my website using DNS name over http. But If I use the IP, there is no redirection. I have disabled all plugin and theme and the redirection is still there. So I was wondering if there was an internal redirection in wordpress ? Here is CURL tests (cloudflare is disabled) :

With IP :

```
curl  -v  http://109.XXXXXXXX
* About to connect() to 109.XXXXXXXX port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 109.XXXXXXXX...
* Connected to 109.XXXXXXXX (109.XXXXXXXX) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 109.XXXXXXXX
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2021 08:13:13 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 163
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Last-Modified: Wed, 17 Jun 2020 20:01:33 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< Server: o2switch-PowerBoost-v3
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-control" CONTENT="no-cache"><META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi"></head><body></body></html>
* Connection #0 to host 109.XXXXXXXX left intact
```

With DNS :

```
curl  -vs  http://www.loop4live.com
* About to connect() to www.loop4live.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 109.XXXXXXXX...
* Connected to www.loop4live.com (109.XXXXXXXX) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: www.loop4live.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2021 08:14:38 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< cf-edge-cache: cache,platform=wordpress
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
< X-Redirect-By: WordPress
< Location: https://www.loop4live.com/
< Server: o2switch-PowerBoost-v3
<
* Connection #0 to host www.loop4live.com left intact
```

Why is there a 301 with "X-Redirect-By: WordPress" (all plugins disbabled) with DNS and not with IP ?

Thanks for your help.
Regards,
Aurélien

Comment: When you connect to the IP, the response is not the content of your website. It is a default server page. Do you have a .htaccess in your hosting or is it a server configuration?

Comment: Your webserver is set up with a virtual host for your domain, and only server your website with the right Host header. This is normal for many websites hosted on the same webserver that share an IP, but you can set one up as default so that if there's no Host header match (e.g. when using the IP) it will still pick one website not the default test page.

Comment: However I haven't heard of o2switch-PowerBoost-v3 - is that a reverse proxy, or a version of Apache or NGINX, or something else? So I can't point you at the right configuration documentation.

Comment: I also doubt this is the same problem you're having with Cloudflare and the REST API.

Comment: In Cloudflare, you can set it up to force HTTPS (SSL/TLS >> Edge Certificates >> 'Always Use HTTPS'). Maybe try disabling that, if you want to allow HTTP-requests.

Comment: The place I have faced redirections in WordPress is I forgot to change the WordPress-address to having HTTPS (under Settings >> Generel). If that is still set to `http://...`, then WordPress will catch the HTTP-request and start handling it. And if there is a plugin trying to force HTTPS, then it can stumble, redirect and/or fall. But it sounds like that you want to allow HTTP-requests.

Comment: No, I want to use full https, but I spent a lot of time to find where the problem come from so I'm testing several ways. I've already tried to disable all https force in cloudflare, to pass in flexible or full ssl. The only way to have something working is to disable all cloudflare. I don't understand why my REST API respond with a too many redirects. The site_url function returns with https. My URL configuration in wordpress is set with https. I have a `.htaccess`, but without redirection.
If I curl on https from the origin server, I got a 200 code. So no redirection... But perhaps wordpress

Comment: Can you work out what the redirects are that WordPress is generating? I'm not sure what information you get back from Cloudflare, but if it's not enough you might have to add some logging to WordPress itself e.g. in wp_redirect or in any place it's called from REST or authentication code.

Comment: @AurélienBenoit try not to derail your own question by posting comments as solutions, I've converted it into a comment and migrated the other comments

Comment: ok, sorry. Yes @Rup, I will try to debug but it's not the easiest thing. Thanks. I keep going.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're sending your request plain HTTP on port 80 so it's only fair it redirects you to the 443 HTTPS, that's the normal behavior of any web server.